# Visual studio like search

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I want to implement Visual Studio like search. For now I want to make it search my `UserControls`, and on click it should open them in `Tab`.
I'm not searching for code, just for the right guidelines and the right terminology to try to implement this.
Thanks for any advice.

Example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

For searching in your `UserControl` collection I would use `LINQ`.

```
List<UserControl> results = (from UserControl control in list_of_usercontrols where (control.SomeParameter.ToLower().Contains(SearchParameter) || control.OtherParameter.ToLower().Contains(SearchParameter)) && nnn.IsEnabled select nnn).Distinct().ToList();
```

For displaying results I highly recommend `ListView`. I use it to show results in my WPF app, it's incredibly fast.

```
listView1.ItemsSource = results;
```

You can set `ItemTemplate` for your `ListView`.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="listView1" BorderThickness="0" SelectionMode="Single"  >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label FontSize="15" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherProperty}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThirdProperty}" ></TextBlock>                 
                    </StackPanel>
                </Label>
                <Label Content="{Binding FourthProperty}" Grid.Row="1" Padding="5,0,0,5"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```